# Adaptive modelling using GEKKO sysid

Tags: python, loops, regression, autoregressive-models, gekko

I have 100 points of data that I'm trying to describe using `sysid` in `GEKKO`. At some point ( t = 50 in this case) the data changes significantly and the prediction is no longer accurate. I'm trying to include an if statement that evaluates actual vs predicted and generates a new model (new `yp` ) if the prediction is x times bigger than the model. Here's my sample code. The loop continues evaluating `yp` at each point in time but it should be evaluating `yp_new` now.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# load data and parse into columns
t = np.linspace(0,1,101)
u = np.linspace(0,1,101)
y = np.zeros(len(t))
y[:50] = np.sin(u[:50])
y[50:] = np.exp(u[50:]/500)
# generate time-series model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
# system identification
na = 2 # output coefficients
nb = 2 # input coefficients
yp,p,K = m.sysid(t,u,y,na,nb,diaglevel=1)
print(yp)
for i in range(len(t)):
    difference = np.abs((yp[i]-y[i])/max(0.01,y[i]))
    if difference>=0.2:   #If the difference is >20%
        yp_new,p_new,K = m.sysid(t,u,y,na,nb,diaglevel=0)
        print('Recalculating at i  = ' + str(i))
print(yp_new)
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,u)
plt.legend([r'$u_0$',r'$u_1$'])
plt.ylabel('MVs')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.plot(t,yp)
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.plot(t,yp_new)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I use the ARX model `m.arx(p)` to give updated predictions once the `sysid` is done. The system identification isn't typically used each cycle, only when an update to the model is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to update `yp` to be the new yp value `yp = yp_new` or else just return `yp` when doing the next system identification. However, the data that you are using to redo the `sysid` calculation is the same as the data that you used previously so there is no change in the model prediction. Are you trying to update the time-series model only with the most recent data such as `yp_new,p_new,K = m.sysid(t[i:],u[i:],y[i:],na,nb)`?

[image: System Identification]

The model currently updates on cycles that do not agree with the original time-series model prediction.

```
Recalculating at i  = 10
Recalculating at i  = 11
Recalculating at i  = 12
Recalculating at i  = 13
Recalculating at i  = 14
Recalculating at i  = 15
Recalculating at i  = 16
Recalculating at i  = 17
Recalculating at i  = 18
Recalculating at i  = 19
Recalculating at i  = 20
Recalculating at i  = 21
Recalculating at i  = 22
Recalculating at i  = 23
Recalculating at i  = 24
Recalculating at i  = 25
Recalculating at i  = 40
Recalculating at i  = 41
Recalculating at i  = 42
Recalculating at i  = 43
Recalculating at i  = 44
Recalculating at i  = 45
Recalculating at i  = 46
Recalculating at i  = 47
Recalculating at i  = 48
Recalculating at i  = 49
Recalculating at i  = 50
Recalculating at i  = 51
Recalculating at i  = 52
```

If you include just the most recent data then it only recalculates at cycles 10, 42, 46, and 48.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# load data and parse into columns
t = np.linspace(0,1,101)
u = np.linspace(0,1,101)
y = np.zeros(len(t))
y[:50] = np.sin(u[:50])
y[50:] = np.exp(u[50:]/500)
# generate time-series model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
# system identification
na = 2 # output coefficients
nb = 2 # input coefficients
yp,p,K = m.sysid(t,u,y,na,nb)
yp_init = yp.copy()
print(yp)
j = 0
for i in range(len(t)):
    difference = np.abs((yp[i-j]-y[i])/max(0.01,y[i]))
    if difference>=0.2:   #If the difference is >20%
        j = i # get cycle where the last update occurred
        yp,p,K = m.sysid(t[i:],u[i:],y[i:],na,nb)
        print('Recalculating at i  = ' + str(i))
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,u)
plt.legend([r'$u_0$',r'$u_1$'])
plt.ylabel('MVs')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.plot(t,yp_init)
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.plot(t[j:],yp)
plt.show()
```

[image: Updated sysid]